# remove unused/bad index to speed up response from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have table with stat below

```
Rows :       4,639,162             
Reserved :   7,183,216 KB
Data :       5,978,536 KB
Index Size : 1,199,840 KB
Unused :         4,840 KB
```

I have used `sp_spaceused 'TableName'` for this stat.

And table information is like below

```
index_name                         index_description                                   index_keys
IX_tbl_tablename_1                 nonclustered located on PRIMARY                     lng_clientid, str_facility_mims, str_group, str_eq_circ_id, int_tml_no
IX_tbl_tablename_fullreport        nonclustered located on PRIMARY                     str_eq_circ_id, str_facility, str_group
IX_tbl_tablename_lng_clientid      nonclustered located on PRIMARY                     lng_clientid
PK_tbl_tablename_1                 clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY   lng_id, lng_clientid
```

I am not expert on index but does these index seems okay ??

EDIT : I am Concerned about different Index created and having some common columns. Eg : Clustered Index is created with lngid and clientid , but there is non-clustered index too with only clientid. So is okay ??

Comment: In order to know whether indexes are useful, we'd need to understand the data in the table and the typical query patterns - not something that really lends itself to solving in a general way on a Q&A website.

Comment: I agree but I am concerned about index created have some common columns.. eg you can see clustered index created with combination of lng_id and clientid but there is one more non clustered on clientid only...same way other two also share some common column.. So is is okay ??

Comment: Indexes are only useful to queries that filter on their leftmost n columns (where n is between 1 and the number of column in the index). A query that just filters on `lng_clientid` can't benefit from the clustered index. But narrow indexes can be beneficial in certain circumstances - so whilst `IX_tbl_tablename_1` *could* be useful for a query that just filters on `lng_clientid`, there may be a reason why a narrow index just on `lng_clientid` has been created.

Comment: You should also look at the index usage statistics report in SSMS, to be sure there aren't indexes that aren't used at all.